# IO::Select loop is somehow keeping child from exiting?

Tags: perl, select, io

I have a perl IO::Select loop for running a command (with no stdin) and saving it's output into a variety of logs.

It's worked great for a number of years, but suddenly it's misbehaving with one particular command.  The command runs to completion and exits properly if it's run from the command line, but when I run it from this perl code then after it's done (as seen from the logs) the child process won't exit, and it just sits in a hung state.  I don't have strace rights on the systems this is happening on, so I can't see exactly what is stuck.

The code is essentially:

```
    # Start process
    open(local *nostdin, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
    my $pid = open3('<&nostdin',
       my $outH = gensym(),
       my $errH = gensym(),
       $command
    );

    # Setup select
    my $sel = IO::Select->new();
    $sel->add($outH);
    $sel->add($errH);

    # Select loop
    while (my @ready = $sel->can_read()) {
        foreach my $handle (@ready) {
            my $bytesRead = sysread($handle, my $buf='', 1024);
            if ($bytesRead <= 0) {
                warn("Error reading command out $!\n  Command: $command\n") if $bytesRead;
                $sel->remove($handle);
                next;
            }
            if ($handle==$outH) {
                syswrite(SYSOUT,$buf) if $stdoutOpen;
                syswrite(SYSLOG,$buf) if $logOpen;
            }
            if ($handle==$errH) {
                syswrite(SYSERR,$buf) if $stderrOpen;
                syswrite(SYSLOG,$buf) if $logOpen;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anything I could be doing wrong?  And even if there is a mistake, how can the perl I/O loop keep the child process from doing it's exit?  It seems once the child exits it would close all it's I/O and we'd finish this loop (as has always been the case with this code).

---

I've done some tests using waitPid and some output, and it looks like the $outH is closing, but $errH never has any data and never closes, and then I can see from waitPid that the child has exiting.

So I open two pipes, for child out and child err.  The child uses the output pipe and never the error pipe.  Then the child closes the output pipe and exits, somehow this exit isn't closing the error pipe.  How is this happening?  Is this something a child could even do on purpose?

Comment: *"... how can the perl I/O loop keep the child process from doing it's exit?"* - I think this is the wrong question. It is the decision of the program itself to exit, not of the parent process (i.e. your perl program). So you need to ask what are the conditions inside the child program which make it exit and how these conditions change if the program is running inside a normal shell or inside your program. Given that this problem seems to happen only with a specific command you need to look at this command. Unfortunately you don't provide any further information about this so we cannot help.

Comment: So the `while` loop completes but the child stays afterwards? (What when the program completes?)  What kind of a thing is the `$command` itself?  That can surely lock things up if it wants.

Comment: "Hung" is not an actual state. What is its actual state (e.g, as obtained using `ps`)? I would expect it to be a zombie since you don't reap it anywhere.

Comment: Tip: `!defined($bytesRead)` is an error. `defined($bytesRead) && $bytesRead == 0` is not an error, so it's not valid to use `$!` then. It just means that EOF has been reached. `$bytesRead < 0` can't happen.

Comment: Tip: If `$outH==$errH` is possible, then you can write the same message to the log file twice. If `$outH==$errH` isn't possible, you should be using `elsif` instead of `if`

Comment: Tip: `sysread` returns immediately if there's any data to read (even if it's less than the requested amount), so there's no point in requesting such a small amount (1024). I would consider 4*1024 or 8*1024 an absolute minimum.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Here are some answers:

1) I don't have much control over the child program, but I can't imagine how it would know it would be running inside this loop, and I know the child is not maliciously getting stuck.
2) The child is not a zombie process, it's just stuck running after it would have normally terminated (as it does if I run the command without gathering output in this select loop
3) I'll look at the bytesRead error
4) In this case I am not worried about $outH==$errH
5) I can look at increasing the sysread amount, but I doubt that would be causing this issue

Comment: Thanks for response.  I still don't get what the program behavior is -- "_sits in a hung state._" -- do you mean that the program locks up (hangs) in/after that `while`?  If not then how do you know what the child does?  (Logs never completed and `ps` shows the process ... in what state?)

Comment: Is this deadlocking? (Does the code drop out of that `while` or not?)

Comment: The child never exits though it otherwise appears to run fine, and my code stays in the while loop.  But as mentioned, when I run the same command outside of this code it terminates as expected.

Comment: I'm not even sure how I could write the external command to be aware of whether it was being run from this select loop or just from the command-line if I wanted to, which made me suspect that something was wrong with my select loop.

Comment: Okay - I've been able to reduce the length of the child process from >4 hours and have been able to run some tests, so I'll update the question.

Comment: See the last two paragraphs, after the horizontal-rule in the question for the new info.

Comment: Can give an example of how `$command` looks like? Also show how the handles `SYSOUT`, `SYSERR`, and `SYSLOG` are set up

Comment: Also as noted by @ikegami, you should probably check if `$bytesRead` is defined before doing the check `if ($bytesRead <= 0)`. If it is not defined an error has occured. `syswrite` may also return `undef` indicating an error has occured

Comment: Yes - I've changed it to:   "if (!defined($bytesRead) || $bytesRead == 0) {"

Comment: The command that is called is another perl script that calls a variety of other tools, and I don't have access to the source of all of them nor an easy way to find out how they handle I/O at all the other levels.

But the question is still raised - how could you possibly make a child that would act this way if you wanted to??

Comment: SYSOUT, SYSERR and SYSLOG are all appending to files.

Comment: It can get stuck in the outer while loop if  `$sel->remove()` is not called, but from your code it seems that cannot happen. Anyway, try to add this line at the top of the outer `while` loop: `syswrite(SYSOUT,"count: " . $sel->count() . "\n");` . It should give you some more information about what is going on

Comment: @HåkonHægland - is at 2 until the exit, then it's at 1

Comment: Interesting - if I use the timeout for can_read and call it multiple times after the process exits, then it finally gets the read of 0 bytes for $errH and closes it.  But it takes about 10 seconds and multiple can_read() attempts - but doesn't work if I don't specify the timeout.  I'm beginning to suspect this is a perl bug where can_read is getting hung and not noticing the closing/exiting.

Comment: Re "*if I use the timeout for can_read and call it multiple times after the process exits, then it finally gets the read of 0 bytes for $errH and closes*", That indicates that the program you actually ran used some buffered I/O (readline, read or eof). These read data from the system and places it in a buffer, so there is nothing left to read as far as the system (select) is concerned. That's why you have to use sysread and nothing else.

Comment: I don't understand entirely - why is it that the can_read() hangs indefinitely, but if I call can_read(<timeout>) it is able to realize that the handle closes?